# Getting error "Blank email address" when attempting to submit a Mailchimp form with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, mailchimp

### Relevant function

```
function subscribe(to_send, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: to_send,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) { console.log('Response', data) },
        error: function (data) { console.log('FUUUUU: ' + data) }
    })
}
```

### Variables passed in

```
to_send = http://evaline.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=76ee17f86cd92d4984c0046f8&id=15deb1bbee&c=?
```

and `to_send = JSON.stringify(data)`, where data is the following:

```
data = {
    "email_address": inputs[1].value,
    "email_type": "html",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "status_if_new": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields": {
        "FNAME": inputs[0].value
    },
    "interests": {
        "9b4ccc9f43": isInvestor,
        "82636e7cd9": isEmployee,
        "c8b187e22d": isBusiness,
        "798cc04c42": isUser,
        "d750ac8858": isOther,
    }
}
```

Where inputs[i] evaluate properly to strings, and isSomeRole evaluates to a boolean. I confirmed with a console.log that they do actually properly evaluate, into something like this:

```
"{\"email_address\":\"a@a.io\",\"email_type\":\"html\",\"status\":\"subscribed\",\"status_if_new\":\"subscribed\",\"merge_fields\":{\"FNAME\":\"a\"},\"interests\":{\"9b4ccc9f43\":false,\"82636e7cd9\":false,\"c8b187e22d\":false,\"798cc04c42\":true,\"d750ac8858\":false}}"
```

...which is the properly stringifyed data.

### On execution of subscribe()

When I execute subscribe(), it appears to properly submit, running the success: function(data) bit, with the response being the following:

`Response – {result: "error", msg: "Blank email address"}`

This is the exact same response I get if I execute `subscribe('', url)` - seems like `data` isn't being attached/sent at all...

### To conclude...

I'm really confused. Should I *not* be stringifying `data`? Should I be doing something else with that payload? Am I missing something in my ajax statement?

Comment: Singe you are using the `data` attribute, it should be set up as an Object with key - value pairs. For example: `?id=1355` would be `{ id: 1355 }`

Comment: Should I instead be parsing that JSON object to read as `key=value&key2=othervalue` etc.?

Comment: Bingo, you've got it.